# why is my movie coming as lines on youtube?

Tags: upload, youtube, video-streaming

I'm trying to upload an introduction to my open source program on YouTube.

It plays well (although the quality is horrible) on my local machine.

I used LiVES on Ubuntu to create the final version. It's an ogv file.

Strangely, when I play it on YouTube, it is just a weird looking output with only sound and some lines/tiles.

The video link is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncFqnLZ-amE

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks!

Note: I've tried uploading this about 4 times now.

Comment: Does your file work on the desktop ok?

Comment: Yes, all my files (with various encoding formats) work PERFECTLY well locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with OGV on [youtube](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=7b9148c46c6b6f90&hl=en) but the thread is a little old. Here is a new [thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=31a5174deca3ff88&hl=en) however.

I think you'll need to convert to avi. Here is a [blog post](http://www.markandey.com/2010/09/how-to-fix-ogv-file-to-upload-on.html) that addresses the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I believe the OGV format is the root cause. But AVI does not do a good job. I tried the Flash format instead and it is good. Furthermore, the AVI file was HUGE - at least 10 times as big as the OGV. But the Flash file is about 3 times as big. I cannot explain this but this is my first hand experience. The video is FINALLY up - after a week of struggle! Thanks. BTW, the link to my file is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNrfaEkjfZQ